# Error when Determining ssh fingerprints of new instances

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

I have tried to create new cluster using `OpsCenter 5.2.4` but I got this error:

```
Error: Fingerprint Detection failed: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
```

in the logs of OpsCenter `/var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log` I got this error:

```
2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 []  INFO: Determining ssh fingerprints of new instances.
2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 [] ERROR: /usr/bin/ssh-keyscan had some issues:
        stdout=
        stderr=        getaddrinfo None: Name or service not known^M

2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 [] ERROR: /usr/bin/ssh-keyscan had some issues:
        stdout=
        stderr=        getaddrinfo None: Name or service not known^M

2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 [] ERROR: /usr/bin/ssh-keyscan had some issues:
        stdout=
        stderr=        getaddrinfo None: Name or service not known^M

2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 [] Error determining fingerprints
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        Failure: exceptions.TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found

2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 [] ERROR: Fingerprint Detection failed: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
            return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/cloud/Ec2Launcher.py", line 582, in _determine_fingerprints

          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
            return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/SecureShell.py", line 148, in get_remote_ssh_key_map

          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send(result)

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/SecureShell.py", line 370, in _get_remote_ssh_keys_in_bulk

2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 []  WARN: Marking request 1ca29951-2ce1-49a2-9a92-5555c93064ce as failed: Fingerprint Detection failed: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 []  WARN: Marking request 3e815163-648d-4681-9893-7abf5dd67aff as failed: Fingerprint Detection failed: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 [] ERROR:
2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 []  WARN: Marking request f59e8ea2-1765-4145-a981-c087d8825b50 as failed: Fingerprint Detection failed: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 [] Unexpected error provisioning cluster.
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        Failure: exceptions.TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found

2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 []  WARN: Marking request f59e8ea2-1765-4145-a981-c087d8825b50 as failed: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 [] ERROR: Launching instances failed (with an unexpected error): Fingerprint Detection failed: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

OpsCenter provisioning dev here. This is telling you the operation that failed:

```
2016-10-09 10:02:06+0000 [] ERROR: /usr/bin/ssh-keyscan had some issues:
    stdout=
    stderr=        getaddrinfo None: Name or service not known
```

Which is probably network related. Can you run ssh-keyscan against the host in question or are you able to ssh to it in general? I'm guessing not and that you need to mess with network-firewalls, iptables, and/or your routing until you're able to ssh from the OpsCenter server to the target hosts.

Also note that the provisioning features in OpsCenter 6.0.x are light-years ahead of what's in 5.2.x. I strongly suggest you upgrade.